# Getting Custom GeoJSON File To Work In HighMaps

Tags: json, highcharts, geojson, highmaps

I currently have a custom .geo.json file that I've created from a county shapefile using ogr2ogr. I would like to manually add values for each county and I've studied [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/geojson/) jsfiddle but, I'm not quite sure how to put the two together. I'm particularly interested in the following line of code from the jsfiddle:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=germany.geo.json&callback=?', function (geojson) {
```

Is this where I should be focusing my efforts?

My custom .geojson file is located [here](http://shearanalytics.net/mass_counties.geo.json).

Comment: I'm still not getting the map to show up with the data... I've converted the shapefile to geojson using QGIS and I believe that I have the coding correct. (http://jsfiddle.net/axp09171/dL7nt16t/) Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add properties is, when you to still have the shapefile, to import it in QGIS (http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) edit the attribute table via properties / attributes. There you can add/remove columns and change the values etc. When you are ready simply save the layer as GeoJSON.

If you want to do it the hard way, you can also open the GeoJSON file in your favorite texteditor and edit the JSON structure. Normally a featurecollection would look something like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "My Point"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-45, -45]
    }
  },{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "name": "My LineString"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [45, -45],
        [45,45]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In there you see two features, a point and a linestring feature. The features contain a properties object, in there you can add the properties you want. So for example change:

```
"properties": {
    "name": "My Point"
},
```

To:

```
"properties": {
    "name": "My Point",
    "description": "Awesome feature", 
    "number": 1,
    "array":, ["a", "b"]
},
```

Then save the file when you're done and if your not sure, you can even validate the entire collection or single features using something like GeoJSON lint: http://geojsonlint.com/

For that line you were interested in is a method from [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) called `$.getJSON` which loads a JSON file into your current script from an local or external location. To use it, give it two parameters. The first is the url to load the data from, `//example.org/data.geo.json` or `/my/local/folder/data.geo.json` and the second a function which executes after the data is loaded, so you can handle your data, assign it to something or so. For example:

```
$.getJSON('//example.org/data.geo.json', function (data) {
    // here 'data' contains the geojson object for you to use
});
```

More info on the getJSON method can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/